# Unwanted indices are getting created in my ES cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

Unwanted indices are getting created in my ES cluster. For eg bellow

```
green  gpworv1.html       5   1          0            0      1.1kb           575b 
green  rgspaa1.html       5   1          0            0      1.1kb           575b 
green  raeeno1.html       5   1          0            0      1.1kb           575b 
green  nnwrsa1.html       5   1          0            0      1.1kb           575b 
green  nrrvwo1.html       5   1          0            0      1.1kb           575b
```

Answer (score 0):

In your elasticsearch.yml file add below code and save it.

action.auto_create_index: 0